# MySQL Copy table procedure fails

Tags: mysql, copy, procedure, dynamic-sql

What am i doing wrong with this procedure??

```
# Copy tabel 
CREATE PROCEDURE `table_backup`(tablename varchar(50))
begin
set @copy_from = tablename;
set @copy_to = CONCAT(tablename, `_`, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d_%m_%yt%H_%i_%s'));
CREATE TABLE @copy_to LIKE @copy_from;
INSERT @copy_to SELECT * FROM @copy_from;
end

CALL table_backup('table_name');
```

Comment: You can't just use table or column names from variables. Use Dynamic SQL for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to perform your query dynamically. This is how you can achieve it in a stored procedure:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create procedure dynamic_query()
   -> begin
   -> set @query=concat("select *from DemoTable2033 where Id=3");
   -> prepare st from @query;
   -> execute st;
   -> end
   -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
```

You will need to perform the `create table` and `insert into` as dynamic query. Depending on your settings you might need to perform them as separate dynamic queries, using the same pattern.

Read more at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/implement-dynamic-sql-query-inside-a-mysql-stored-procedure

Comment: Thank you for the input. I believe I have to build the sql from php python or else before executing. The idea was to have tablename as variable.

Comment: @groyk then you do not need to perform SQL dynamic querying. In that case you can simply generate a string by your Python/PHP program and inject the tablename into it.